# Is it a well-established convention that pdf is lower case but CDF is upper case?

Tags: notation

I'm wondering if the Wikipedia page for "[probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)" is wrong in having the acronym be all lower-case "pdf".
The page for "[cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)" has all upper case "CDF".

Comment: It seems to be fairly common (if inconsisent) to do it, but I don't know that I'd go so far as to call it convention.

Comment: Why does it matter?  Is there any possibility of confusion?